# In a Linux system call, are system call parameters preserved in registers after the syscall finished (at the sys_exit tracepoint)?

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls, tracepoint

Is it guaranteed to be able to read all the syscall parameters at `sys_exit` tracepoint?

[sysdig driver](https://github.com/draios/sysdig/blob/dev/driver/)  is a kernel module to capture syscall using kernel static tracepoint. In this project some of system call parameters are read at `sys_enter` tracepoint, and some other parameters are read at `sys_exit` (return value of course, and contents in userspace to avoid pagefault).

Why not read all parameters at `sys_exit`? Is this because some parameters may be not be available at `sys_exit`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it guaranteed to be able to read all the syscall parameters at `sys_exit` tracepoint?

Yes... and no, we need to distinguish parameters from registers. Linux syscalls should preserve all general purpose userspace *registers*, except the register used for the return value (and on some architectures also a second register to indicate if an error occurred). However, this does not mean that the input *parameters* of the syscall cannot change between entry and exit: if a register holds the value of a pointer to some data, while the register itself does not change, the data it points to could very well change.

Looking at [the code](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.7/source/include/trace/events/syscalls.h#L42) for the static tracepoint `sys_exit`, you can see that only the syscall number (`id`) and its return value (`ret`) are traced. See note at the bottom of my answer for more.

> Why not read all parameters at `sys_exit`? Is this because some parameters may be not available at `sys_exit`?

Yes, I would say that ensuring the correctness of the traced parameters is the main reason why tracing only at the exit would be a bad idea. Even if you get the values of the register, you cannot know the real parameters at syscall exit. Even if a syscall *per se* is guaranteed to save and restore the state of user registers, the syscall itself can alter the data that is being passed as argument. For example, the `recvmsg` syscall takes a pointer to a `struct msghdr` in memory which is used both as an input and an output parameter; the `poll` syscall does the same with a pointer to `struct pollfd`. Furthermore, another thread or program could have very well modified the memory of the program while it was making a syscall, therefore altering the data.

Under specific circumstances a syscall can also take a very long time before returning (think for example of a `sleep`, or a blocking `read` on your terminal, an `accept` on a listening socket, etc). If you only trace at the exit, you will have very incorrect timing information, and most importantly you will have to wait a lot before any meaningful information can be captured, even though that information is already available at the entry point.

---

**Note on `sys_exit` tracepoint**

Although you could thecnically extract the values of the saved registers of the current task, I am not entirely sure about the semantics of doing so while in the `sys_exit` tracepoint. I searched for some documentation on this specific case, but had no luck, and kernel code is well... complex.

The chain of calls to reach the exit hook should be:

- Arch specific entry point (e.g. [`entry_INT80_32`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/x86/entry/entry_32.S#L1052) for x86 `int 0x80`)

  - Arch specific entry handler (e.g. [`do_int80_syscall_32()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/x86/entry/common.c#L84) for x86 `int 0x80`)

    - [`syscall_exit_to_user_code()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/entry/common.c#L261)

      - [`syscall_exit_to_user_mode_prepare()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/entry/common.c#L238)

        - [`syscall_exit_work()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/entry/common.c#L220)

          - [`trace_sys_exit()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/entry/common.c#L227)

If a deadly signal is delivered to a process during a syscall, while the actual process will never reach the exit of the syscall (i.e. no value is ever returned to user space), the tracepoint will still be hit. When a signal delivery of this kind happens, a special internal return value is used, like `-ERESTARTSYS` ([see here](https://lwn.net/Articles/17744/)). This value is *not* an actual syscall return value (it is not returned to user space), but rather it is only meant to be used by kernel. So it looks like the `sys_exit` tracepoint is being hit with the special `-ERESTARTSYS` if a deadly signal is received by the process. This does not happen for example in the case of `SIGSTOP` + `SIGCONT`. Take this with a grain of salt though, since I was not able to find proper documentation for this.

Comment: Thanks for this excellent answer. I basically understand the reason behind this. But there is just one thing I want to confirm that I tried the example you mentioned about issuing a `read` with an invalid buffer, but the `sys_exit` is reached with a return value `EFAULT`. Is there some other example  that demonstrate that a system call could be killed and not reaching `sys_exit`?  Thanks again!

Comment: @user2828102 yeah you're right that's probably not the best example, I forgot that `read` checks the arguments and if the buffer pointer is invalid it returns `EFAULT` without killing the process. In any case you can test this quite easily if you run `strace -f cat` in one terminal (it will block waiting on a `read`) and then open another terminal and issue `ps aux | grep cat` to find the PID of the `cat` process and then `kill -9 PID` to kill it. [Example](https://i.imgur.com/eHtYtFL.png).

Comment: Although strace show a '?' as the `read` return value, I wrote a demo LKM to print a message at `sys_exit` tracepoint, turns out the `read` still reach `sys_exit` with a return code `-512` means `ERESTARTSYS`.

Comment: @user2828102 yeah, sorry, I removed that part, check my edited answer.